# Email Attachment Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create an "Attachment" button, Where you can search for a file, and it'll copy the file directory for you. This is combined with an email function.

I can attach an attachment by typing where the file is located. But I want to do it through a button.

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"C:\Attachment.txt");

Mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Is there a fileinputstream to help?  I'm puzzled on where to begin.

Comment: Winforms? ASP .net? WPF? Please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the available Win32 components:

```
    // Configure open file dialog box 
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog(); 

    // Show open file dialog box 
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog(); 

    // Process open file dialog box results 
    if (result == true) 
    { 
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(dlg.FileName); 
        Mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpfsdk/openfiledialog-sample)

Answer (score 1):

check out OpenFileDialog class (assuming you are using c# or winform)

It will allow you to browse for files using windows explorer and returns the path

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user3276954 FileName property will contain the full path to the file